# How can I readably/tersely/correctly check in whether a value is in one of two ranges?

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I need help writing a better code for the following logic:

```
if [[ "$CONDITION1" == "BAD" && "$PERCENT1" -ge 10 && "$PERCENT1" -le 30 ]] || [[ "$CONDITION1" == "GOOD" && "$PERCENT1" -ge 30 && "$PERCENT1" -le 60 ]] || [[ "$CONDITION2" == "BAD" && "$PERCENT2" -ge 10 && "$PERCENT2" -le 30 ]] || [[ "$CONDITION2" == "GOOD" && "$PERCENT2" -ge 30 && "$PERCENT2" -le 60 ]];
then
        echo "RESULT 1"
elif [[ "$CONDITION1" == "BAD" && "$PERCENT1" -gt 30 ]] || [[ "$CONDITION1" == "GOOD" && "$PERCENT1" -gt 60 && "$PERCENT1" -le 100 ]] || [[ "$CONDITION2" == "BAD" && "$PERCENT2" -gt 30 ]] || [[ "$CONDITION2" == "GOOD" && "$PERCENT2" -gt 60 && "$PERCENT2" -le 100 ]];
then
        echo "RESULT 2"
else
        echo "RESULT 3"
fi
```

This is the basis for the conditions:

RESULT 1:
    PERCENT1 is 10-30% if CONDITION1=BAD

```
OR PERCENT1 is 30-60% if CONDITION1=GOOD

OR PERCENT2 is 10-30% if CONDITION2=BAD

OR PERCENT2 is 30-60% if CONDITION2=GOOD
```

RESULT 2:
    PERCENT1>30% if CONDITION1=BAD

```
OR PERCENT1 is 60-100% if CONDITION1=GOOD

OR PERCENT2>30% if CONDITION2=BAD

OR PERCENT2 is 60-100% if CONDITION2=GOOD
```

Result 2 overrides Result 1. For example:

```
PERCENT1 is 10-30% and CONDITION1=BAD AND
PERCENT2>30% and CONDITION2=BAD will result in RESULT 1.
```

Comment: Your description (or code) is misleading. In code there are  PERCENT2, CONDITION2 variables, which are not present in your description. Verify code/description and provide strict information what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question for clarity. CONDITION1 and PERCENT1 belong to the same data set. Same goes for PERCENT2, CONDITION2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't clean this up to much, but it can be made better.  Since you require result 2 overriding result one, you need two if statements, with the override running second.  Technically, you could do it with an elif, with the override being the if, and the inferior one being the elif, but this logic is more difficult to read, and when the complexity of your requirements would produce very long conditions.

```
RESULT=3            # default to result 3
if [[ $PERCENT1 -ge 10 && $PERCENT1 -le 30 && $CONDITION1 = "BAD" ]]; then
   RESULT=1
elif [[ $PERCENT1 -ge 30 && $PERCENT1 -le 60 && $CONDITION1 = "GOOD" ]]; then
   RESULT=1
elif [[ $PERCENT2 -ge 10 && $PERCENT2 -le 30 && $CONDITION1 = "BAD" ]]; then
   RESULT=1
elif [[ $PERCENT2 -ge 30 && $PERCENT2 -le 60 && $CONDITION2 = "GOOD" ]]; then
   RESULT=1
fi

# RESULT 2 should override result one
if [[ $PERCENT1 -gt 30 && $CONDITION1 = "BAD" ]]; then
   RESULT=2
elif [[ $PERCENT1 -ge 60 && $PERCENT1 -le 100 && $CONDITION1 = "GOOD" ]]; then
   RESULT=2
elif [[ $PERCENT2 -gt 30 && $CONDITION1 = "BAD" ]]; then
   RESULT=2
elif [[ $PERCENT2 -ge 60 && $PERCENT2 -le 100 && $CONDITION1 = "GOOD" ]]; then
   RESULT=2
fi

echo "RESULT $RESULT"     # output our result
```

Since it doesn't matter how many times RESULT 1 or RESULT 2 are hit, then the elifs work fine.  Note that I changed your `-ge 30` to `-gt 30` since you used > 30 and not >= 30 in your explanations for the conditions.  Not sure which one was a typo.

Comment: If it does not meet any of the 1st 2 conditions, it should result in RESULT3. Just add it to the last if statement?

Comment: @Afungus I missed Result 3.  Default to it, and result 1 overwrites result 3, result 2 overwrites result 1 & 3.  Then you have your echo at the end.

Comment: By defaulting, do you mean initializing RESULT=0?

Comment: @Afungus no, RESULT=3, b/c we are defaulting to 3.  I've added it to the code above and commented it.